# Can't find variable: props, but I am doing the same thing everywhere?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to display the comment section of a post. The flow goes like this:

1. User opens app
2. User sees Home Screen, which is a flat list of posts (think instagram)
3. User clicks a specific post, which opens the post details screen
4. Details screen shows the comments as a flat list, as well as the post details

I am on step 4, where the details screen loads fine, and I am now trying to display post comments. However, I am running into this error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: props
```

Ok, that is odd, since I am displaying both the flat lists identically (the Home flat list and the comments flat list). Luckily, expo gave me more details:

```
Component Stack
<CommentFeed />
clickedPostPage.js: 75
```

Ok, we go to line 75 of clickedPostPage, and here is the code:

```
<CommentFeed postID = {this.state.postID} />
```

So where I am calling CommentFeed and passing the postID, I get this issue. Here is my comment feed:

```
    class CommentFeed extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isLoading: true,
          commentsArray: [],
          postID: this.props.postID
        };
        this.firestoreRef = 
        Firebase.firestore()
        .collection('globalPosts')
        .doc(this.state.postID)
        .collection('comments')
        .orderBy("date_created", "desc");
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.unsubscribe = this.firestoreRef.onSnapshot(this.getCollection);
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.unsubscribe();
    }
  
    ...
```

I am only calling props in the constructor, where I get the postID from the clickedPostPage.js so I can query the correct post comments in the database. However, this is not working. I went ahead and tried debugging the issue, adding CommentFeed to the stack, where ClickedPostPage is already added:

```
[App.js]

        <Stack.Screen name="CommentFeed" 
          component={CommentFeed}
          options=  {{
            headerLeft: null
        }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="ClickedPostPage" 
          component={ClickedPostPage}
          options=  {{
            title: "post details",
              headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: 24,
              },
            headerLeft: null
        }}/>
```

I cannot seem to figure out where my issue is. This is a bit different from my Home Screen flat list implementation, because this one is embedded a few pages into the app. Other than that, the actual logic is the same. I cannot think of why I am getting the error `Can't find variable: props`.

Comment: `constructor(props)` would do it

Comment: @remeus as soon as I posted it I noticed my issue. Added the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe I was so stressed over this. The issue was in my CommentFeed:

```
class CommentFeed extends React.Component {

constructor(props) { <--------------------- I forgot to pass props here.
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      commentsArray: [],
      postID: this.props.postID
    };
    this.firestoreRef = 
    Firebase.firestore()
    .collection('globalPosts')
    .doc(this.state.postID)
    .collection('comments')
    .orderBy("date_created", "desc");
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.firestoreRef.onSnapshot(this.getCollection);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    this.unsubscribe();
}
```